# Wordpress change "Sorry No Results Found!"

Tags: wordpress

I have the Real Homes theme installed. Modern version theme.

On a page I have no items and it displays the message:

**Sorry No Results Found!**

How do I change that to: **Check again later!**

In what file can I find the html output code ?
I've searched through all the files and I cannot find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they correctly localized the theme, you can install a Plugin like [Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) to change the translation of that string. Just search for "Sorry No Results Found!" in the translation template.